# How to attach or match an image to text

Tags: android, string, image

I want an image to change exactly when a string changes ( please revise, if not it's called a string, please refer below)

I have this

```
   public static String[] questions = {
            "Dog attacks you",
            "Fire inside your house"

    };

    public static String[] answers = {
            "kick it hard",
            "safely exit"
   };

}
```

the question strings are being shuffled then matched to the string answers
now if the user typed in the correct text in the string a button will pop up
(i had already coded for a button)
now i want an image (a dog attacking someone to match "dog attacks you" then change to "fire inside your house" with a burning house picture when the button is clicked after the user got the right answer in "dog attacks you"

-i just assumed that "dog attacks you" to be the first one to show up, just an example anyway."

now my question is that is there a way to do it?

Comment: create a model class of `Question`, add fields with image, question text, correct answer text to it.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to use [HashMap](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashmap-in-java-with-example/). A String key with an integer value that links to your image.  
`hashmap.put("Dog attacks you", R.drawable.dogattacksyou);`